# I tried to do a git update in Visual Studio and it told me there were conflicting changes

Tags: git, github

I then tried this:

```
alan$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   J/Views/HomeTab/Pages/Details.xaml
    modified:   J/Views/HomeTab/Pages/Details.xaml.cs

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
alan$ git pull
Updating 1771faf..191be38
Fast-forward
 J.iOS/Info.plist | 4 ++--
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
```

I didn't make any changes that I know of to Info.plist. Is there a way I can just accept those changes and then carry on with pushing my changes to origin master?

Note that after doing the git pull, when I go back to Visual Studio and select Version Control > Update Solution,  here's what I get:

[image]

Comment: In your second screenshot I see "Rebasing" - What command did you start exactly? Seems that you started a rebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any conflict change there after you do a `git pull`. It looks like someone has pushed something to `master` branch while you were working on your branch, and that someone changed the file `J.iOS/Info.plist`. When you did a git pull you just got the latest changes from master remote to your local branch.

Try from terminal to see what's happening. Do a `git status` and rely on that. Try to close VS and open it again to see if it show you the same message.

Comment: Thanks, I tried and it worked now.  I will mark as correct later.